# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint.The conflict occurred in database

Tags: javascript, sql, asp-classic

I am having a asp application and it has a  triple drop down list from database and if i submit the form it needs to insert the data from that list box too...but i am getting error as

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_HospitalEmployeeMaster_Ref_HospitalId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "test_db", table "dbo.hospitalmaster", column 'Hospital_Id'.

Kindly help me..

Comment: What value did you submit for that field?

Answer (score 2):

You inserted a value in `HospitalEmployeeMaster` more particularly on `Hospitalid` field that is not consistent with the `Hospitalid` in `HospitalMaster`.

For example let's say this is your `HospitalMaster` table below:

```
 HospitalID       HospitalName
 ----------       ------------
   1              ABC Hospital
   2              XYZ Hospital
   3              L.A. Hospital
```

Then your `HospitalEmployeeMaster` let's say have this fields

```
 ID       EmployeeID      HospitalID    AdmissionDate
 ---      ----------      ----------    -------------
 113      10001           1             11/02/2013
 242      10002           2             10/23/2013
 214      10003           4             8/1/2013
```

In the first two records it is all valid because `HospitalID` value could be found in `HospitalMaster`. However, the third record has `HospitalID = 4` which could not be found in `HospitalMaster` and therefore an error.